# Diode identification marking M and T. (SOD-123 Flat)

Tags: diodes, identification, surface-mount

I need some help to identify these two diodes. (At least to identify the manufacturer). The package is SOD-123 with flat leads (SOD-123F or SOD-123W).

Context: These 2 diodes are assembled on automotive boards so they are probably AEC qualified. Most of the components around are from Japanese brands (Rohm/Renesas/Toshiba).

I think that the significant code is M and T. The others characters are probably lot/date codes.

[image]

[image]